# how can i display text in different colors in a jtextPane

Tags: colors, jtextpane

i want to display a text in a jtextPane but on each time i want it to be with a different color without changing the previous text color if that possible
Any help will be appreciated
thank's in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use [StyledEditorKit.ForegroundAction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/StyledEditorKit.ForegroundAction.html), but also [StyledDocument.setCharacterAttributes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/StyledDocument.html) , or edit the inputAttributes from StyledDocument.getInputAttributes. You can use [StyleConstants.setForeground](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/StyleConstants.html) to edit a MuttableAttributeSet like a SimpleAttributeSet for instance.